# Check finished errors found in 1 file

Tags: 20.04, iso

I build custom ISO Ubuntu 20 according to [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization).
After the custom ISO is ready, I install the OS from it, and at first, the error appears: `Check finished errors found in 1 files`.
Could you tell me how to find this error and fix it?
I already checked md5sum, I read about it.

Comment: You've tagged 20.04, but refer to Ubuntu 20 (which doesn't exist, but is closest to Ubuntu Core 20 which is a different product to 20.04).  The wiki page refers to md5sums, which are deprecated & replaced by sha256sums. (you should have noticed that at the download page https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/20.04/release/)  Note: *this is opinion only, if I knew it was fact, I'd correct the wikipage which I believe to be outdated*.

Comment: If errors are reported and you need help solving the problem, it might be useful to include actionable error messages. There are a million reasons for why something might not be working as expected.

Comment: I have been seeing the same error with the xubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso image. There is no actionable error message. This is a check done when you start the boot process - it  reports the error exactly as described (Check finished errors found in 1 files! You might encounter errors.). Otherwise, everything still seems to work. To be clear: I checked the SHA256 checksum, reburned the image to my USB, burned it again with Startup Disk Creator, tried again with dd, tried a different USB, downloaded from a different mirror, downloaded a torrent, and then tried all those things again...

Comment: a related issue (and link to a bug report) is here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/691933

Answer (score 2):

It is mentioned in [this bug report](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/691933) that "*Windows write System Volume Information on any filesystem it can understand (EFI boot partition in this case) which causes the checksum to fail.*". This matches my experience, where the error was reported, repeatably, if the USB stick is inserted into a live Windows system between the time it was created and when it is booted.

Looking closer, a folder `System Volume Information` is added to the small `EFI (Fat-12/16/32)` partition.

[image: EFI partition in context]

[image: EFI partition contents]

**Advice**: *Avoid inserting live USB while Windows is running.*

Comment: FYI, I successfully created a bootable USB thumb drive (no errors when Windows not involved) using the "Restore Disk Image" feature of 'gnome-disk-utility'.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I can discover from looking at this bug report and discussion ([Check error with 20.04-desktop ISO](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/691933))  it appears this is just a built-in limitation of the file checking where the efi.img file is modified when it is loaded and that really means it can't be verified.  I would advise go ahead and ignore this error! That is what I have done with my Xubuntu installation and I have had no problems at all (since then I have also noticed this error when installing Ubuntu Mate and I also ignored it in that case as well!)

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to stop checking or skip this process.
2. Use "Try Ubuntu".
3. Then, Install Ubuntu 20.04 lts from inside "Try Ubuntu".
   Note: Don't remove your boot-able Pen-drive until it saying to remove it.

I faced same issue like yours and above was helpful.

Comment: you could format your buttons better with <kbd> ... </kbd>.